# A is a 3x3 matris such that $A^3$ = 0. Is 0 an eigenvalue of A.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If A is a 3×3 matrix with $A^3$ = 0, is 0 an eigenvalue of A?

Prove or give counter example.

The answer given to this question is since $A^3 = 0$, A is not invertible and therefore 0 is an eigenvalue. I don't quite understand why A is not invertible. Any other proof is also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $0=\det A^3=(\det A)^3$, hence $\det A =0$.

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ were invertible $A^{-3} A^{3} = I$, but this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative proof that zero is an eigenvalue: You can assume that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, with corresponding eigenvector $x$. Then $A^3x=A^2(Ax)=A^2(\lambda x)=\lambda A^2x=...=\lambda^3x$. But $A^3=O$, so $0=\lambda^3x$, which implies that $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue. In fact, zero is the only eigenvalue.

To show that $A$ *has* an eigenvalue at all, we just use the fundamental theorem of algebra: the characteristic polynomial has at least one complex root, and that root must be an eigenvalue, as taught in linear algebra courses.

Comment: Note that this proof can be extended to show that any nilpotent matrix (i.e. matrix $A$ s.t. $A^n=0$) has only the eigenvalue 0.

Comment: This doesn't show that $A$ has an eigenvalue zero. It shows that the only possible eigenvalue of $A$ is zero.

Comment: Ok, but that's remediable via the fundamental theorem of algebra, piece of cake :)

Comment: Assuming you work over $\mathbb{C}$. However, the result is true over any field so it is not an optimal workaround.

Comment: Sure. Duly noted. Depending on what context the asker is in at the moment however, this answer may very well be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ were invertible then we would have
$$ I = A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}AAA = A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}0 = 0 $$
which is not the case.